# How to get age of persons from their raw EEG data(edf file)?

Tags: signal-processing, mne-python, eeglab, european-data-format

I want to work with the ages of individuals from their eeg records for research. I am using these tuh_eeg dataset (https://isip.piconepress.com/projects/tuh_eeg/downloads/tuh_eeg_abnormal/). I have tried different methods in matlab and python to somehow get the age but i failed. Please help me with this.
[As you can see in the image, when i opened an eeg file with "edfbrowser" , there is a text showing "Age". That means the age is somewhere in the file but i can not access it](https://i.ibb.co/RP0bwNG/eeg-ss.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the function getPatient() of edfreader.py in [EDFlib](https://www.teuniz.net/edflib_python/)

Unfortunately, your EDF file is in an older (deprecated) version of EDF
that does not yet support the birthdate of the subject but you can filter
the string returned by getPatient() for "age:".

FYI, in EDFbrowser go to File -> Info to see all information stored in the EDF header.

[Here](https://gitlab.com/Teuniz/EDFlib-Python/-/tree/master/examples) you find a code example of how to use edfreader.py.